# Merits and demerits of using java.security.acl in a Java EE project

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, acl

I'm going to implement *Access Control List* using *java.security.acl* for displaying permitted items in a user account page.

For instance, there are some users and user groups and the users as well as the groups can have some permissions. There are some links in the user account page, they are add, delete, edit and view. The user account page is same for all users, but the links (add, delete, edit and view) will be displayed differently according to the user permission.

I can achieve this task with *collection framework*. I'm going to implement it with *java.security.acl* in an initial development of an *ERP* (*enterprise application*). I want to know whether there will be any security loop hole or something with this implementation (even in future). Why I doubt is that [when I visited a site which says](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch18_01.htm) `The use of this package is not recommended`.

Is there any advantage of using this package instead of *collection framework*? Is there any case which needs the implementation of this package in a *Java EE* project? All your recommendations, suggestions and advices are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it might be too late to provide an answer, but I came across the question and I had just been reading up things on ACL.

First of all, the classes in the `java.security.acl` have been superseded by the classes in the `java.security` packages As mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/acl/package-summary.html). As a general policy, while doing new development, I prefer to use only the latest APIs.

Second; the classes in the `java.security` packages are probably meant only for securing the system resources like `file I/O` and `network I/O` or printers and so on. Securing your application's domain object is not what they were meant for, as mentioned in the last paragraph [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc2.html).

You could look into [spring-security-acl](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html) for this purpose, or roll your own solution (as you mentioned in the question).

**Is there any advantage of using this package instead of collection framework?**

Well, depends on what you are trying to achieve, but, in your case, the question is not relevant.

**Is there any case which needs the implementation of this package in a Java EE project?**

No, not required unless you need to access resources on the *client-side*, or planning to use *custom* socket-based communications with SSL/TLS.